# how to tar last few lines

Tags: tar

Is it possible to create a tar of only the last few lines of a file?
Something like this does not seem to be working.

```
tail abc.xml | tar -zcf bac.tar.gz
```

I am trying to keep the compressed file size as small as possible. I do also want to transfer it over the network as fast as possible.

Comment: Check this [link][1]..


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516481/add-last-n-lines-of-files-to-tar-zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have standard input as the source for tar but what do you want to do? There is no need to create a tar archive for just a single file. You can pipe directly to gzip:

```
tail abc.xml | gzip - > bac.gz
```

`bac.gz` will then contain the last 10 lines of your file (compressed).

But I suspect that your question does not reflect what you want to achieve: you really want to send the last part of the XML file as a compressed gzip file?